# Split list into two equal length based on the prevous items [python]

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
l_html_pdf = ['http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408290006828315.html',
 'http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201408290006828315_1.pdf',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408280006817950.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201407170006375136.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201404190005463448.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403310005349643.html',
 'http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201403310005349643_1.pdf',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403280005340354.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201401210005016082.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201310220004535166.html']
```

How to separate the `l_html_pdf` into two equal length lists:

```
l_html = ['http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408290006828315.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408280006817950.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201407170006375136.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201404190005463448.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403310005349643.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403280005340354.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201401210005016082.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201310220004535166.html']

l_pdf = ['http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201408290006828315_1.pdf',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201403310005349643_1.pdf',
 '',
 '',
 '']
```

Some HTML links do not have corresponding PDF links. So, I wish to assign the `''` item into the `l_pdf`.

Comment: Does every file have this `ANxxxxxxxxxxxx` pattern, `AN` followed by 12 digits?

Comment: Yes. Any idea?@ddejohn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution, with regex and `itertools` (both part of the standard library):

```py
import re
import itertools


pattern = re.compile(r"(AN\d{12})")
l_html = []
l_pdf = []


for _, group in itertools.groupby(l_html_pdf, key=lambda s: pattern.findall(s)[0]):
    html, *pdf = group
    l_html.append(html)
    if pdf:
        l_pdf.append(pdf[0])
    else:
        l_pdf.append("")
```

If your data *isn't* already sorted, then you'd want to do this:

```py
def file_helper(s):
    return pattern.findall(s)[0]


for _, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(l_html_pdf, key=file_helper), key=file_helper):
    html, *pdf = group
    l_html.append(html)
    if pdf:
        l_pdf.append(pdf[0])
    else:
        l_pdf.append("")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but here's a potential solution using a regular expression to capture the unique part of the filename, and `collections` (both part of the standard library):

```py
import re
import collections


pattern = re.compile(r"(AN\d{12})")
paired_files = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {"html",: "", "pdf": ""})


for filename in l_html_pdf:
    key, *_ = pattern.findall(filename)
    if filename.endswith("pdf"):
        paired_files[key]["pdf"]
    else:
        paired_files[key]["html"]
```

Output:

```py
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002551AA0E310>,
            {'AN201310220004': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201310220004535166.html',
                                'pdf': ''},
             'AN201401210005': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201401210005016082.html',
                                'pdf': ''},
             'AN201403280005': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403280005340354.html',
                                'pdf': ''},
             'AN201403310005': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403310005349643.html',
                                'pdf': 'http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201403310005349643_1.pdf'},
             'AN201404190005': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201404190005463448.html',
                                'pdf': ''},
             'AN201407170006': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201407170006375136.html',
                                'pdf': ''},
             'AN201408280006': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408280006817950.html',
                                'pdf': ''},
             'AN201408290006': {'html': 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408290006828315.html',
                                'pdf': 'http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201408290006828315_1.pdf'}})
```

This data structure could potentially be easier to work with, depending on what you're doing, but if you *insist* on having separate lists:

```py
l_html, l_pdf = zip(*[list(d.values()) for _, d in paired_files.items()])
```

Output:

```py
In [5]: l_html
Out[5]:
['http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408290006828315.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201408280006817950.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201407170006375136.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201404190005463448.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403310005349643.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201403280005340354.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201401210005016082.html',
 'http://fund.eastmoney.com/gonggao/000060,AN201310220004535166.html']

In [6]: l_pdf
Out[6]:
['http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201408290006828315_1.pdf',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_AN201403310005349643_1.pdf',
 '',
 '',
 '']
```

Or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71477152/6298712) answer.